# How can I move the punctuation from the end of a string to the beginning?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, split

I am attempting to write a program that reverses a string's order, even the punctuation. But when my backwards string prints. The punctuation mark at the end of the last word stays at the end of the word instead of being treated as an individual character.

How can I split the end punctuation mark from the last word so I can move it around?

For example: 
When I type in : Hello my name is jason!

I want: !jason is name my Hello

instead I get: jason! is name my Hello

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone
{
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");

        String input = userInput.nextLine();

        String[] sentence= input.split(" ");

        String backwards = "";

        for (int i = sentence.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            backwards += sentence[i] + " ";
        }

        System.out.print(input + "\n");
        System.out.print(backwards);
        }
}
```

Comment: How is it possible with your backward definition? `!` is not a separate word to get what you want. It can be done but your reverse a string order thinking is wrong.

Comment: On each word, check to see if it `endsWith` something that is not a letter.  If so, move it to the start of the word.  And voila.

Answer (score 2):

Manually rearranging Strings tends to become complicated in no time. It's usually better (if possible) to code *what* you want to do, not *how* you want to do it.

```
String input = "Hello my name is jason! Nice to meet you. What's your name?";

// this is *what* you want to do, part 1:
// split the input at each ' ', '.', '?' and '!', keep delimiter tokens
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, " .?!", true);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = st.nextToken();
    // *what* you want to do, part 2:
    // add each token to the start of the string
    sb.insert(0, token);
}

String backwards = sb.toString();

System.out.print(input + "\n");
System.out.print(backwards);
```

Output:

```
Hello my name is jason! Nice to meet you. What's your name?
?name your What's .you meet to Nice !jason is name my Hello
```

This will be a lot easier to understand for the next person working on that piece of code, or your future self.

This assumes that you want to move every punctuation char. If you only want the one at the end of the input string, you'd have to cut it off the input, do the reordering, and finally place it at the start of the string:

```
String punctuation = "";
String input = "Hello my name is jason! Nice to meet you. What's your name?";
System.out.print(input + "\n");
if(input.substring(input.length() -1).matches("[.!?]")) {
    punctuation = input.substring(input.length() -1);
    input = input.substring(0, input.length() -1);
}

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, " ", true);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    sb.insert(0, st.nextToken());
}
sb.insert(0, punctuation);
System.out.print(sb);
```

Output:

```
Hello my name is jason! Nice to meet you. What's your name?
?name your What's you. meet to Nice jason! is name my Hello
```

Comment: So I can get a deeper understanding, can you elaborate on this line? :

String token = st.nextToken();

Comment: The ``StringTokenizer`` will split the input at every char that matches one of the chars in the delimiter string (second argument in ``new StringTokenizer(input, " .?!", true);``, so ' ' aka space,``.``,``?`` and ``!`` in this example). Every call of ``st.nextToken()`` will return the next piece of the split string - the class calls these pieces tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps:

(1) Check for the `!` character in the input

(2) If input contains `!` then prefix it to the empty output string variable

(3) If input does not contain `!` then create empty output string variable

(4) Split the input string and iterate in reverse order (you are already doing this)

You can refer the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
     String originalInput = userInput.nextLine();
     String backwards = "";
     String input = originalInput;

      //Define your punctuation chars into an array
       char[] punctuationChars = {'!', '?' , '.'};
        String backwards = "";

          //Remove ! from the input
         for(int i=0;i<punctuationChars.length;i++) {
          if(input.charAt(input.length()-1) == punctuationChars[i]) {
              input = input.substring(0, input.length()-1);
              backwards = punctuationChars[i]+"";
              break;
          }
        }

        String[] sentence= input.split(" ");


        for (int i = sentence.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            backwards += sentence[i] + " ";
        }

        System.out.print(originalInput + "\n");

        System.out.print(input + "\n");
        System.out.print(backwards);
    }
```

Comment: The title specifically says  *"move the punctuation from the end of a string to the beginning"*.  He just provided an example using `!`.And you should also consider punctuations in the middle of the string. Please edit your answer and code to satisfy all the symbols( which is in more generic way)

Comment: @SkrewEverything Yes, you are right, updated my answer by defining the punctuation chars into an array and checking the char and adding.

Comment: I think you forgot about editing some comments and last `if` block. And please change `!` from your explanation in the starting and replace it with `? . !`

Comment: @SkrewEverything Is it looking fine now ?

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers, need to separate out the punctuation first, and then reorder the words and finally place the punctuation at the beginning.

You could take advantage of String.join() and Collections.reverse(), String.endsWith() for a simpler answer...

```
String input = "Hello my name is jason!";
String punctuation = "";
if (input.endsWith("?") || input.endsWith("!")) {
    punctuation = input.substring(input.length() - 1, input.length());
    input = input.substring(0, input.length() - 1);
}
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
Collections.reverse(words);
String reordered = punctuation + String.join(" ", words);
System.out.println(reordered);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work for you

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class ReplaceSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String originalString = "TestStr?";
        String updatedString = "";
        String regex = "end\\p{Punct}+|\\p{Punct}+$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(originalString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
            int start = matcher.start();
            updatedString = matcher.group() + originalString.substring(0, start);<br>
        }
        System.out.println("Original -->" + originalString + "\nReplaced -->" +      updatedString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't split by spaces; split by word boundaries. Then you don't need to care about punctuation or even putting spaces back, because you just reverse them too!

And it's only 1 line:

```
Arrays.stream(input.split("\\b"))
    .reduce((a, b) -> b + a)
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/MKdphc).